# java.lang.IllegalStateException when trying to give volume to Flink job on AWS EKS

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

Im trying to run Flink jobs using the Apache Flink Kubernetes operator. I am able to run my stateless jobs with ease, but when I try to run a stateful one, like the one in the example here:

https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/blob/main/examples/basic-checkpoint-ha.yaml

I keep getting the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The base directory of the JobResultStore isn't accessible. No dirty JobResults can be restored.
```

When I run this FlinkDeployment on my local machine with hostPath volume or persistentVolumeClaim, it works (with minikube). But when I try it on EKS, I get that error. This is my deployment YAML:

```
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: basic-checkpoint-ha-example
spec:
  image: flink:1.17
  flinkVersion: v1_17
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "2"
    state.savepoints.dir: file:///flink-data/savepoints
    state.checkpoints.dir: file:///flink-data/checkpoints
    high-availability.type: kubernetes
    high-availability.storageDir: file:///flink-data/ha
  serviceAccount: flink
  jobManager:
    resource:
      memory: "2048m"
      cpu: 1
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "2048m"
      cpu: 1
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: flink-main-container
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /flink-data
              name: flink-volume
      volumes:
        - name: flink-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: flink-data-pvc
  job:
    jarURI: local:///opt/flink/examples/streaming/StateMachineExample.jar
    parallelism: 2
    upgradeMode: savepoint
    state: running
    savepointTriggerNonce: 0
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: flink-data-pvc
spec:
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
```

I am not really sure how to access my task manager and job manager logs to actually debug this further, as the container keeps dying before that.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/blob/main/examples/basic-checkpoint-ha.yaml example with Minikube and I am encountering the same exact error. Even locally.